# What is the meaning of Transaction?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jta

I've been reading about **"Java Transaction"** , and i've been  confused about what's it? and what's useful in?

Comment: can you elaborate on what you are confused about? otherwise you are going to get very generic definitions.

Comment: @Bala-R I want to know what's exactly the "Java Transaction" purposes in j2ee , and I noticed you said **very generic definitions** .. Is that mean Transaction  have various jobs ??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can google around and find pages like this: http://www.java-tips.org/java-ee-tips/enterprise-java-beans/introduction-to-the-java-transactio.html

but the bottom line is: a transaction is a set of operations which must all succeed or all fail and be reversed (rolled back).

The obvious example is banking: if you transfer money from savings to checking, both updates had better occur, or neither, otherwise there will be an error.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the best place to start are:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transaction_processing

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID

Thanks,
Nitin